# Android emulator failed to start after a successful aosp build

Tags: android-source

Follow the official [build guide](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building).
I downloaded the master branch and built the aosp_arm-eng target. The build process was fine, but when I tried to start the emulator, it failed with the following logs:

```
.......
emulator: GPU emulation enabled using 'host' mode
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: VERBOSE: MultiDisplay.cpp:312: create display 0
emulator: VERBOSE: MultiDisplay.cpp:401: setDisplayPose 0 x 0 y 0 w 480 h 800 dpi 0
cannot add library /media/kevin/Data/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
added library /media/kevin/Data/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
cannot add library /media/kevin/Data/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so.1: full
emulator: VERBOSE: load_config.cpp:242: Verified boot params were not found.
.......
emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
emulator: Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '196609'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'both'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '512m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '240'
qemu-system-aarch64: -chardev socket,port=46269,host=localhost,nowait,nodelay,ipv6,id=modem: Failed to connect socket: Connection refused
emulator: Done with QEMU main loop
```

I had searched around, and tried install some [vulkan related packages](https://linuxconfig.org/install-and-test-vulkan-on-linux).

I'd also tried to [create an Android Virtual Device](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds) by using the built files,the avd just showed an empty black screen. But the AVDs created from the offical images works well on my computer.

System Info:

Ubunutu 20.04

CPU: 14-Core Intel Xeon E5-2680 v4 (-MT MCP-) speed/min/max: 1199/1200/3300 MHz Kernel: 5.4.0-58-generic x86_64 Up: 1d 23h 10m

Graphics:  Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X] driver: amdgpu v: kernel
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: amdgpu resolution: 3840x2160~60Hz
OpenGL: renderer: Radeon RX 560 Series (POLARIS11 DRM 3.35.0 5.4.0-58-generic LLVM 10.0.0) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8

Comment: Well....This seemed to be a bug of the aosp master branch. The Android-11 branch worked fine here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the master branch....this the bleeding edge branch and has many bugs...

Try the released branches.